# Do I have a chance to open a flash game in the webview today?

Tags: java, android, flash, webview

I find a lot of questions here about flash in the webview. All of them are 2013 - 2014. Then it was already very difficult or even impossible. What about today? Can I somehow integrate flash into the webview? 
If not, what are the options?

Comment: Find something that uses HTML5.

Comment: @TheWanderer This game is on the site.
I do not have access to the source code.

Comment: Then there are no options. Flash is basically dead.

Comment: You can't play Flash games on mobile anymore.